# regex begin with http or https and ends with /download

Tags: regex

I need regex for the following:

must begin with `http://` or `https://` and must end with `api/file/download`

I tried like: `(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)*\/api\/file\/download` but with this one `httt://localhost:4301/api/file/download` gives ok, but this should be rejected because of `httt`

[tester](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: The * means "zero or more times", so your matches aren't actually required to start with either of those options. Also it seems unnecessary to repeat the whole thing, just use `https?:\/\/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(http(s?)://(\w)+.\w+/api/file/download)
```